# Share code between client and server side in a TypeScript web app

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript project, and I have a data(.ts) file (what includes things like title) and I need it both server and client side.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
node_modules/
package.json
README.md
src/
    data.ts
    data.js (compiled data.ts)
    server.ts
    server.js (compiled server.ts)
    public/
        sw.ts
        sw.js (compiled sw.ts)
        [other static resources (.css, .html or other .ts)]
```

src/*.ts files are server side, src/public/*.ts files are client side.

So I want to import data.ts from both server.ts and sw.ts but `require` obviously doesn't work in sw.js.

How can I solve this?
Or what directory structure would be better?

Comment: Have you tried using a module loader?

Comment: The main problem is that I can't request a server side file from the client side - the best would be something like Browserify, but I haven't found any resource regarding the implementation of it to a TypeScript project.

Comment: tsify is an option, but I didn't figure out how can I use tsify and tsc in the same project.

Answer (score 4):

I would organize as follows

```
src/
    common/
        data.ts
    server/
        server.ts
    client/
        sw.ts
```

And compile the whole thing to an `outDir:../public`. Also use `module: commonjs` .

CommonJS works out of the box with node (server) and webpack (client).

Comment: Sorry, I haven't mention that I have other resources - how can I get them to the /public directory? And how can I use webpack for more .ts files?